# Make tag popups display permanently while editing

Tags: feature-request, tags, edits, popups, tag-wiki-excerpt

I hope most of us can agree that there's a problem with tag misuse.
(And I'm sure we'll all disagree on how severe this problem is.)

In line with this, I suggest we make tag popups permanent while you're editing the question or, for 10k users, [edit the tags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) (although less significant, since 10k users *hopefully* know a little better).

Currently, if you type fast enough, you never see the popup:

[image]

And after you press space after the tag, the popup disappears:

[image]

So it's fairly easy to type in a tag without ever seeing the popup, much less reading it.

I suggest, while editing the post, we always show all the tag 'popups'.

A quick draft:

[image]

Since we only allow 5 tags, it should be possible to fit all the excepts on one line without making it too long vertically. Perhaps, as part of this, we should consider lowering the maximum allowable length of tag excepts.

Comment: The permanent popups idea is nice but honestly I would be satisfied if we could at least view the summaries at all when editing.  Currently even if you hover over the tag while editing you can't view the summary.

Comment: This is also a problem when asking a question. Tag wikis don't stay up long enough, and people often misuse tags, while that exact misuse is advised against in the tag wiki. Unless someone explicitly knows about wikis, they simply forget to check them.