# How to address C#/.NET users' mis-use of the [assembly] tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

As a rule, all **C#** and other **.NET** users think that "assembly" is a word invented by Microsoft for their lovely .NET.

So, they persistently tag their questions with [assembly](/questions/tagged/assembly) tag. I have been editing several hundreds of them, and it seems it will never end.

And what is worst - in the [assembly](/questions/tagged/assembly) tag description, there is a warning, but maybe because it is at the end of the text, no one actually read it. Or even worse, they see the known words ".NET" and "C#" and not reading the remaining, put it in the question.

So, isn't it possible to set some kind of warning that to pop when such unbelievable combination of [.net](/questions/tagged/.net)[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) together with [assembly](/questions/tagged/assembly) tags has been selected.

Another (easier) solution is to edit the description of [assembly](/questions/tagged/assembly) tag and make the warning message to use big, bold and red letters: **"Highly incompatible with .NET and C#!"**

What can be the proper solution?

Addendum 1: As @Wooble suggested in the comments, the problem is possibly wider than I thought and there are other sets of incompatible tags. IMO, this means that some general solution is desirable - detection of such pairs and output of a warning message.

Notice that in some rare cases, there are questions that are properly tagged with such combinations - for example a question that asks about .NET compilation issues and refers to the disassembled code.

Comment: maybe propose a new tag like project-assembly ?

Comment: @mehow - new tag for what?

Comment: I don't believe that anyone ever reads any of the tag descriptions when adding tags. I doubt making it bold and red would change that.

Comment: @johnfound In C# and .NET DLLs are called "Assemblies". There are even classes and namespaces in the .NET framework named "Assembly"

Comment: @Wooble - well, I read them.

Comment: This calls for a [tag:.net-assembly] tag

Comment: @Spontifixus: I think he knows that.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak: Which is explicitly recommended in the [assembly] wiki already (albeit with the . in .net).

Comment: @Spontifixus - there is [tag:.net-assembly] for **these** assemblies.

Comment: "As a rule, all C# and other .net users think " I too love blanket assumptions

Comment: @tjennings: You mean blanket *rules* ;)

Comment: It's not limited to this one case (anything tagged [android] [ar] is almost certainly misusing the [ar] tag and I've probably edited it out of about 100 questions), and a feature that gives an extra warning for some tag combinations would be kind of neat. On the other hand, implementation might be... ugly.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn - Why removed [tag:feature-request]? Wooble even cited another incompatible pair of tags, so there can be wider use of such a feature...

Comment: in addition to creating .net-assembly as a tag, the other should probably become assembly-language. Otherwise you're in the same situation as metro was.

Comment: As much as adding a tag for it is the right solution, I don't think it'll actually /fix/ the problem, which isn't so much 'C# and .Net users are dummies' as it's 'People just using whatever tags they think are appropriate without reading them.'

Comment: @tjennings Very true... I recently saw an editor add the [script] tag to a question, although it starts with capitals "DO NOT USE THIS TAG". I rejected it, and IIRC three robo-reviewers accepted it :-(

Comment: This *might* help - [Make tag popups display permanently while editing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201587/make-tag-popups-display-permanently-while-editing).

Comment: I did a title edit, as my first read of the title made me think you meant they were being rude. Which may or may not be the case, but isn't what you are talking about here ;)

Comment: @Wooble What about using the <blink> tag? #html5

Comment: There is also an [assemblies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assemblies) tag for .NET assemblies (.dll and .exe)

Comment: If I have an assembly question, I'm using the assembly tag.  You go make some other tag like [assembly-language] for your ancient low level mongrel script questions.  Foo.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that [assembly](/questions/tagged/assembly) is perfectly legitimate to use for .NET related questions about .NET assemblies. Asm'ers don't own it; they just used it first. (Side note: I've written a Visual Studio plugin for parsing and syntax colouring assembly language code - if I talk about that I can use any assembly tag I like :).

So the solution is to try and disambiguate it, but if you check you'll find that's already been done. [asm](/questions/tagged/asm) has already been synonymised with [assembly](/questions/tagged/assembly), and [.net-assembly](/questions/tagged/.net-assembly) is in wide use.

**TL;DR:** you need a tag cleanup, not a crusade against ignorant C#ers who have never heard of assembly language. Tag cleanups are common; don't get too worked up over it.

Comment: "Asm'ers don't own it" - exactly what I was thinking. The tags are *not* meant to provide a scientifically robust taxonomy of questions.

Comment: Plenty of tags mean many different things.  [tag:MVVM] used to refer to the pattern used in WPF (.net), but then Knockout came along.  We now live in peace and harmony within the same tag.  I resent attempts by dicks to evict me from a tag because they're cranky bastards who write obscure code using chisels on granite.  To them I say "Good day, sir."  *I said good day!*